# Twilio Click-to-call: Say message to second caller if first hangs up?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Newbie to Twilio here.  I'm calling a user via calls.create:

```
client.calls.create(options)
    .then((call) => {
      console.log('Call ID='+call.sid);
      response.send('Dialing User at '+userPhone);
    })
```

and then calling a second person and connecting the calls together via dial.number:

```
app.post('/outbound/:calleeNumber', function(request, response) {
    const calleeNumber = request.params.calleeNumber;
    const twimlResponse = new VoiceResponse();
    twimlResponse.say('Thank you for calling.  Please hold while we connect you.',
                      { voice: 'woman' });
    const dial = twimlResponse.dial({action:'http://' + request.headers.host + '/calleeendscall'});
    dial.number({url:'http://' + request.headers.host + '/screencall'}, calleeNumber);
    response.send(twimlResponse.toString());
});
```

If the second callee hangs up first, I can play a message to the first from within the url specified by the "action" parameter of .dial.  However, if the FIRST callee hangs up first, the call is ended immediately.  Is there any way I can catch the second callee before the call is disconnected and play a "they hung up, thanks for calling" message?

Comment: Have you tried using a conference?

Comment: I considered it, but as this will always be a 2-person call, I'm trying to avoid the extra fraction of a cent per minute for conferencing.

Comment: I think Alex is right, to control both sides of the call this way you'll want to investigate conferences.